# Unable to override boot method in Model laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5.6

I tried to override boot() method in laravel 5.6 using following code

```
class Organization extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $table = 'organizations';
    //protected $cascadeDeletes = ['organization_members'];

protected $fillable = ['name', 'user_id','logo','description','status'];

protected static function boot ()
{
    parent::boot();

    Organization::deleting(function (Organization $organization) {


    foreach ($organization->organization_members()->get() as $organization_member) {

        $organization_member->delete();
     }

    });
}
public function organization_members()
{
   $this->hasMany(OrganizationMembers::class);
}
```

}

Organization is the parent model and organization member is the child model with foreign key that refers to id in organization.I tried to delete the organization member upon deleting() event in organization model.But its not deleted and never enters into boot method.

Comment: How are you deleting your organization? Events do no work when using mass deletion.

Comment: only one organization is deleted at a time

Comment: Can you show me your code where you delete?

Comment: Inside repository i am calling a function to delete organization      public function model()
    {
        return 'Apps\Models\Organization';
    }  public function deleteOrganization($id)
    {
     $org_delete = $this->model->where('id', $id)->delete();
       
    }